# ClassNotFoundException when running my applet

Tags: java, applet, package, classnotfoundexception, dos

I'm facing some trouble to run an applet using appletviewer command line in ms-dos.
this is my project tree :

```
Project
|___classes
|       |___org 
|            |___test
|                  |___Test.class
|
|__src
    |___org       
         |___test
               |___Test.java
```

Here is Test.java source file :

```
package org.test;

import java.applet.Applet;

/*<applet code="org.test.Test" width="200" height="100" 
codebase="..\..\..\classes\org\test"></applet>*/

public class Test extends Applet{

    public void init(){

    }

    public void start(){

    }

    public void stop(){

    }

    public void destroy(){

    }

}
```

I read in an article that the appletviewer only need a file where there is an applet tag inside it, so that it will parse that file to retrieve the  tag. That is what I did with the commented line in the source file above.

The source file compiles without any error. Then I try to run it. So I go into the folder where my source file is, and I try this :

> prompt\Project\src\org\test>appletviewer Test.java

Here is the error that occurs :

> java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.test.Test
>           at sun.applet.AppletClassLoader.findClass(AppletClassLoader.java:211)
>           at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
>           at sun.applet.AppletClassLoader.loadClass(AppletClassLoader.java:144)
>           at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
>           at sun.applet.AppletClassLoader.loadCode(AppletClassLoader.java:662)
>           at sun.applet.AppletPanel.createApplet(AppletPanel.java:785)
>           at sun.applet.AppletPanel.runLoader(AppletPanel.java:714)
>           at sun.applet.AppletPanel.run(AppletPanel.java:368)
>           at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)

I think that the error comes from the first line of my java source file, because when I remove it, all works fine. But I just don't know why...
Could someone explain me, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe it should be

```
codebase="../../../classes"
```

And you should be trying to run the .class file, not the .java file, in which case the current directory should be `classes` when you try to run it.

Comment: Ok, I was just starting to get crazy!! Thank you very much! I now understand.

Comment: `"..\..\..\classes"` should be `"../../../classes"`

Comment: @AndrewThompson : It seems like both notations (\ and /) work fine. I tried them both.